Why are there holes drilled through a basement slab near exterior walls about 18” apart?
These 1” diameter holes are covered with a plastic plug. I’m wondering why they were drilled, and if I should fill or recover them after damaging some of the plastic plugs while removing the adjacent carpet tack strips.


was this the prior site of an interior wall for a finished basement, attaching a sill plate to the slab?

Not enough info for an answer, but I wonder if they were from doing some sort of mud-jacking or floor raising for a sinking basement concrete floor.

The holes are an indication of drilling through the slab to inject termiticide as a treatment for subterranean termites.
This is common in slab homes in the southeast of the United States.
Plugs are normally a fraction of an inch thick. The purpose is just to close the opening. And be a convenient axcess point if treatment is needed again in the future.
Cover any caps that were damaged. Even some duct tape over the top will suffice. There is no immediate danger, just wash your hands after working on them.
